# User Customized Links List

Tags: 2013, list, custom-list

I have a list of links that I want each of my users to be able to customize in several ways:

- There will be a "master" list of links which are security trimmed by groups
- Users should be able to change the order in which the links are listed
- Users should be able to add custom links to the list, which only they have access to, and can change or delete

What I currently have is my "master" list of security trimmed links, accomplished via a "Group" column that a workflow reads to set the permissions for a given list item.

What I still need is a way to:

1. Keep a second list of per-user, user-specified links that will eventually aggregate with the "master" list of links
2. Save the sort order of the aggregated list of "master" and user-created, security-trimmed links

Don't worry about any of the client-side of things, I'm still trying to grasp the concept of SharePoint lists and what they're capable of, and just need to figure out the best way to structure my data.

Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

## 2 is easy. If you click "Add view" in the ribbon, you can make a personal view where you can arrange what columns you see and in what order. You can also filter by created or modified with [Me] to only see things you have edited. This view will be saved and you can access it by clicking "All Items" in the breadcrumb list at the top of the page and then selecting the name of the view.

Based on what you're asking about custom links I don't think it is possible, but there are a couple of options. You could create a view that groups the links by created  to see each person's links individually. Or you could create a column called "Viewable By" or something and have options like "Everyone, Individuals, Managers" and then do some views that filter based on that column. I do not believe you can manage security settings for a view, but it might be possible with Sharepoint Designer.

Or you could have a list for each user or have each user create a list on their personal site (accessed by clicking their name in the top right corner) and then have your master list call data from those individual sources, but that would require the use of Sharepoint Designer.

Comment: Thank you for your response Katelyn. I'm going to be retrieving/updating the data using javascript and REST calls in order to present/manipulate the data in a custom UI, so views won't be much help in my situation. I'm also hoping to avoid any direct interaction between the end user and the SharePoint list itself, so unfortunately your other suggestions won't quite work either. :-/